# Using visual studio 2013 built in message box via DTE object

Tags: visual-studio

I'm developing visual studio project template. 
During the template installation I perform some long operations that I want to let the user know about. 
I've already seen the DTE statusbar progress method but I prefer output the message in visual studio built in message box. 
 
Is it possible?

Comment: It should already work that way, probably every VS user has seen that automatic popup with the marquee progress bar a bit too often.  If you haven't written the slow code yet then use Thread.Sleep(5000) to verify it pops up.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. The status bar progress message is located at the bottom of the IDE window while I couldn't find access to the IDE popup message.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it.

The assemblies:

```
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.10.0
```

In the using statements:

```
  using IOleServiceProvider = Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider;
```

The code:

```
 private IVsThreadedWaitDialog2 _progressDialog = null;

 private void StartProgressDialog(string operation, string statusBarText, int total)
    {
        if (_progressDialog == null)
        {
            IOleServiceProvider oleServiceProvider = _dte as IOleServiceProvider;
            IVsThreadedWaitDialogFactory dialogFactory = new ServiceProvider(oleServiceProvider).GetService(
                        typeof(SVsThreadedWaitDialogFactory)) as IVsThreadedWaitDialogFactory;
            IVsThreadedWaitDialog2 dialog = null;
            if (dialogFactory != null)
            {
                dialogFactory.CreateInstance(out dialog);
                _progressDialog = dialog;
            }
        }

        if(_progressDialog != null)
        {
            _progressDialog.StartWaitDialogWithPercentageProgress("Wait Dialogue", operation, null, null, statusBarText, false, 0, total, 0);
        }
    }

    private void TerminatePreogressDialog()
    {
        if (_progressDialog != null)
        {
            int canceled;
            _progressDialog.EndWaitDialog(out canceled);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateLongOperationMessage(string operation, string progressMessage, int step, int total)
    {
        if (_progressDialog != null)
        {
            bool canceled;
            _progressDialog.UpdateProgress(operation, progressMessage, progressMessage, step, total, true, out canceled);
        }
    }
```